# How to add components after the constructor (f. e. using mouseClicked event)

Tags: java, swing

I can add components in the constructor, but I cant add the same component after the constructor is done. Can somebody help me out? Here is my example code:

```
public class MainFrame extends JFrame implements MouseListener{

    JButton btnAdd = new JButton("Add new button");
    int i = 0;
    Container container;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MainFrame frame = new MainFrame();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public MainFrame() {
        container = getContentPane();
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(800, 700);
        container.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        container.add(btnAdd);
        btnAdd.addMouseListener(this);

        // Add 2 additional buttons
        i++;
        container.add(new JButton("Btn " + i));
        i++;
        container.add(new JButton("Btn " + i));
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Layout = " + container.getLayout());
        i++;
        container.add(new JButton("Btn " + i)); //this is not happening! WHYYYY????
        System.out.println("Mouse klicked");
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
    }
}
```

If I add the buttons in the constructor, everything works fine. But when I try adding the same component in the mouseEvent, it just doens´t happen. I think it has something to do with the layout, but I am not sure.

Comment: Two better strategies: 1) Add the component to a panel with cardlayout that is added in the constructor. The other component added would be a blank panel to which the mouse listener is added. When that panel detects a mouse click, it flips to the other card showing the button. 2) Since it is a button, add that button in the constructor, but disable it. until mouse click.

Comment: Also as noted by @FrakCool. For a button, add an action listener rather than a mouse listener.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call [`revalidate()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#revalidate()) and [`repaint()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#repaint()) methods in your `mouseClicked()` method after you've added the new buttons...

But also you shouldn't be using `MouseListener` in a `JButton` but an [ActionListener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html) instead.

You should also not be extending `JFrame` in your class, if you need to extend something extend a `JPanel`, see: [Java Swing using extends JFrame vs calling it inside of class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41252329/java-swing-using-extends-jframe-vs-calling-it-inside-of-class)

Comment: @Frankcool 
I did try repaint(), but it didnt work since the revalidate() was missing. The revalidate()-method is new to me. Didnt know about it.
Thanks for the support!